# MongoDb and java dao implementation

Tags: java, mongodb, dao

I would like to know if there is a way to implement the DAO design pattern to connect to a Nosql database (MongoDB) and do all the CRUD opérations.
In my research i found all the solutions are related to spring support for MongoDB but I am using only pure Java.

Comment: I also having this problem try to do basic CRUD just using MongoDB, but it hard.

Comment: I spend a month to learn this too, not much resource indeed with Java.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using Morphia instead : https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/ Pretty much does the job.

Here's a quick tutorial : https://dzone.com/articles/using-morphia-map-java-objects

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what's so special about morphia, can't we work directly with the mongoDB java driver?

Comment: Of course you can. It all depends on what you want to do. Here's a good discussion on what you should choose and when : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/morphia/V1ubjRq8668/BoJ6nKY8wtIJ

Comment: Very useful discussion!

Comment: Yes indeed it helped me!